# "Posted on" function in Underscores.me theme

Tags: php, wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm using the "posted on" function in my Underscores theme, and what it does, is output both the `published date` and (if having been updated) the `update date`

The function:

```
function underscores_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
    }

    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
    );

    $posted_on = sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: post date. */
        esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', 'underscores' ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
    );

    echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

}
```

What I need is to only output the published date if **NO** revisions/updates have been made, in the form of:

> Published on {date}

-And if it **HAS** been updated, then **ONLY** output the update date, in the form of:

> Updated on {date}

This means I need to also prepend text to indicate either published or updated status.

To begin with, I don't know why Underscores would want to output both the published and updated date on top of each other, so it's possible I'm using it wrong.

I tried to mess around with the code to fit my needs, but it didn't work. This was a while ago, and I deleted the code, but I'll explain my thought process:

My understanding is, it's checking if the published date is not equal to the modified time, and if not, it echoes the published date.

I figured I needed to set up an `if/else`, so if a modified time does not exist, print `published on` and if a modified time **DOES** exist, then print `updated on`, but I don't know whether to edit the initial `$time_string`, `$posted_on` or the `echo` down below.

It's likely simpler than what I'm making it out to be, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was painfully simple.

Just prepend the text-status in each `$time_string` up top, and remove the "Posted on" in the parameter in `$posted_on`

Comment: I'm too having a similar issue and googling landed me here. Yet I still don't quite get it. Would you be kind to elaborate a bit? Thanks ;)